# Can I Configure Code Search in TFS 2018 Same server?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS 2015 U3.

I am working on Migration  of TFS  from 2015 U3 to TFS 2018 RC2.

We have a TFS 2015  current set up as follows:

- Single App Tier- includes vNextBuild agents (Windows Server 2012 R2)
- Single Data Tier - SQL server 2016 is used

If i want to configure code search server in the same application tier, is there any issue? what would be the process to do that?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? This is all clearly explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Search can be used on any size physical server or virtual machine that
>   runs TFS 2017 or above. It can be configured on the same server as
>   TFS, or on a separate server dedicated to Search. When configuring
>   Search on the same server as TFS, you must take into account the
>   existing CPU utlization factor due to TFS itself. In most cases you
>   should consider configuring Search on a separate server.

Please go through the article below, and follow the steps there to configure Search feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/administration

By the way, [TFS 2018 RTM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes) is available, you can upgrade to RTM version instead of RC2. Also, TFS 2018 requires SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1), make sure your SQL Server meets this requirement.